# SQL Server add check constraint for ordered pair with specific value for one of the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the following table

[image: table]

I want to add constraint which says "The ID numbers must be unique". This means that I cannot have the same Value when the Type is ID_NUMBER, but I can have the same value with another Type (e.g USERNAME).

How can achieve this ? I was thinking about some kind of check constraint on the two columns but I don't know how to provide "ID_NUMBER" for the value of one of the columns in the constraint.

Comment: Isn't this a simple compound key? A `UNIQUE` index can be created on two columns: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_Table_Type_Value ON Table(Type, Value)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a filtered unique index:

```
create unique index unq_table_value on table(value) where field = 'ID_NUMBER';
```

Comment: This works fine, but only for table which doesn't have duplicates. Is it possible to create the index without checking for duplicates (something like NO CHECK when using constraints ) ?